# Decompose nuclear norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-norms, nuclear-norm

Let $A$ and $B$ be two square matrices such that $A^\top B = 0$ and $B^\top A = 0$.  How can we show that $$ \|A+B\|_{nuc} = \|A\|_{nuc} + \|B\|_{nuc}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $|M| = \sqrt{M^TM}$. Note that $|A|^2$ and $|B|^2$ commute with $|A|^2\;|B|^2 = 0$.  Since there exist polynomials $p,q$ with $|A| = p(A^TA)$ and $|B| = q(B^TB)$, we can conclude that $|A|,|B|$ commute with $|A| \, |B| = 0$. So, we have
$$
(|A| + |B|)^2 = |A|^2 + |B|^2 = A^TA + B^TB = |A + B|^2.
$$
So, $|A+B| = |A| + |B|$.

Comment: How are you able to conclude the part about |A| and |B| commuting? I'm not familiar with that result.

Comment: @SethDevlin Because $A$ commutes with $B$, $A$ commutes with $q(B) = |B|$.  Because $|B|$ commutes with $A$, $|B|$ commutes with $p(A) = |A|$.